# Why does angular-chartjs update works in $timeout callback but not in async callback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I've got a angular-chartjs barchart on my page:

And I initialise it with some data:

```
$scope.data= [
  [1,2,3,4]
];
$scope.labels = [1,2,3,4];
$scope.series = ['field1'];
```

And if I add a datapoint after a couple seconds, the chart happily updates:

```
$timeout(function() {
    console.log('timeout');
    $scope.labels.push('');
    $scope.data[0].push(9);
}, 2000);

//the data gains a 9, and the chart updates and now has 5 bars,
//rather than 4.
```

But if I try to do the same thing inside of an async callback, something goes terribly wrong, and the chart fails to render altogether.

```
$http.get( _url_ ).then(function(res) {
     $scope.labels.push('');
     $scope.data[0].push(9);
});
//perhaps something goes wrong behind the scenes with $scope.data
//because the chart wont load now
```

Why is it that doing stuff inside of the callback for the ajax request makes the chart unhappy?

Edit: [here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eVKWwCu54tlxPsXpqqJz), but for some reason, it works fine in the plunker but not in the real application.

Comment: I don't see anything that would require a digest call... can you put this in a fiddle?

Comment: also, i've tried calling $scope.$apply and it said something along the lines of "already digesting"

Comment: @Nix i've created a plunker. really weird: it works in plunker but not in the real application.

Comment: There is something else at play... assuming there are no js errors?  And u are initializing everything the same as you do in the fiddle ?

Comment: OK, well, the page is a stage of components in which other components can be dragged and dropped into that stage. each component is rendered in there by using the `compile` function, which takes a template and a scope as arguments. so, the code above is being run in a particular component's controller function.

Comment: My recommendation is to make your plunkr as close to the real code as possible *or*  update the post and show more of your code.  Beyond that I can't really help without seeing the real code.